# I can't save an Arabic tweet using tweepy in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, arabic, tweepy

so as the title says I hardly tried to figure out how to save tweets using tweepy in python 3.6. I found a solution that I can save it in English but I can't in Arabic. anyone have any ideas how?

the output I get in the CSV file for Arabic tweets is like this

1510123361.875904::\u0623\u0639\u0648\u0630 \u0628\u0643\u0644\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644/FMsjMi2nvF

Thank you in advance.

This is my code

```
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

save = open('ExampleNumber4.csv', mode='w', encoding="utf8", newline=None)


class listener(StreamListener) :
    def on_data (self , data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)['text']
            print(tweet.translate(non_bmp_map))
            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            savefile = str(time.time()) + "::" + tweet
            save.write(savefile)
            save.write("\n\n")
            return (True)

        except KeyError:
            pass


    def on_error(self , status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler (ConsumerKey , ConsumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(AccessToken , AccessTokenSecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth , listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=[u'سيارة'])
save.close()
```

Comment: Pls post the error

Comment: there are no errors appears, the problem is the output in the CSV file is appearing like this : 1510123361.875904::\u0623\u0639\u0648\u0630 \u0628\u0643\u0644\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644/FMsjMi2nvF

Comment: And if you decode that it says '1510123361.875904::أعوذ بكلمات الله ال/FMsjMi2nvF'

Comment: I don’t get what you are saying, how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution.  Please try to make working examples that produce the error of your question next time by including some sample JSON data and skipping the twitter code that we can't run as is.

```
#coding:utf8
import sys
import json
import time
import csv

data = r'{"text": "\u0633\u064a\u0627\u0631\u0629\ud83d\ude00"}' # ASCII JSON
# data = '{"text": "سيارة"}'  # non-ASCII JSON

non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

with open('ExampleNumber4.csv', mode='w', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as save:
    writer = csv.writer(save)
    tweet = json.loads(data)['text']
    print(tweet.translate(non_bmp_map))
    savefile = [time.time(),tweet]
    writer.writerow(savefile)
```

Output:

```
1510208283.7488384,سيارة�
```

Comment: How I can manipulate this code to make it read from file **ExampleNumber4.csv**, encode the ASCII JSON, then reprint it in the same file? I hope my question is clear. Thank you so much sir and sorry for the misconception, this is my first time using the website.